# jQuery or JS - how to wrap an image if the parent is not <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to get it to work.
I need to wrap images that are not "clickable" inside a div.

The images that are children of a  should not be wrapped.

I did the following:

```js
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
  if (!$("img").parent().is("a")) {
    $("img").wrap('<div class="clickable_image"></div>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <img class="alignnone wp-image-60001 size-full" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="yyyyy" width="1400" height="1686">
</p>

<p>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-60003 size-full" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" alt="xxxx" width="1500" height="350">
  </a>
</p>
```

However I am making some mistakes, because it's not wrapping any image. And if I remove the !, it wraps both images. Only the image that is NOT inside a  should be wrapped. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Your title is asking the opposite to the actual question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan was just about to say that.

Comment: `$("img").parent()` will give you all the parents of all the images, so doesn't make sense to use `.is` on multiple elements - going down that route you would need to do `$("img").parent().each(...` then check each one - but better to use an alternative selector to select what you do want in one go (as provided answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the descendent selector to wrap only the `img` elements which are children of `p`:

```js
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
  $('p > img').wrap('<div class="clickable_image" />');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone wp-image-60001 size-full" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="yyyyy" width="1400" height="1686">
</p>
<p>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-60003 size-full" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" alt="xxxx" width="1500" height="350">
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. However I have a plenty of posts and not sure if everywere the img are inside a "p".

` $('.main article p > img')`  works for some test posts. However what class is safer if an image somewhere is not inside a <p>? Let's say is just inside the article but not wrapped in a p?

Comment: In that case change `p` in the selector to a class, and ensure that class is on the parent of every relevant `img` element